# Couldn't load avutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple example in Android Studio to play stream using ffmpegMediaPlayer

I following the instruction in the link https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer

I am getting this error while running the application in the simulator

Generated Error :

```
08-11 15:46:02.619      903-903/com.example.audiostreamingusingffmpeglibrary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.audiostreamingusingffmpeglibrary-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.audiostreamingusingffmpeglibrary-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
            at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaPlayer.<clinit>(FFmpegMediaPlayer.java:620)
            at com.example.audiostreamingusingffmpeglibrary.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 15:46:02.669      275-424/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.audiostreamingusingffmpeglibrary/.MyActivity
```

Gradle build file

```
.....
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/fmp.jar')
}
.....
```

Main Activity

```
.....
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        FFmpegMediaPlayer mp = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new FFmpegMediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(FFmpegMediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mp.setOnErrorListener(new FFmpegMediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(FFmpegMediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mp.release();
                return false;
            }
        });

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://www.brothershouse.narod.ru/music/pepe_link_-_guitar_vibe_113_club_mix.mp3");
            mp.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

.......
```

Comment: did u resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not including the .so files in your compilation.

Try with these steps:

1. Put the four folders with .so files in a new folder called "lib".
2. Compress the folder "lib" in a zip file.
3. Change the file extention from zip to jar.
4. Copy de new jar created in the libs folder of your project.
5. Compile the new jar file in the dependencies.